# How tensorflow realy works?

Tags: tensorflow

Today, I noticed one sentence when reading the caffe2 tutorial, it says

> we just define a protobuf using caffe2 python interface. when we actually want to run the network, we just send the protobuf to c++, and c++ will instantiate a net object from the protobuf, and call the net's run() funtion.

Does tensroflow using the same strategy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are a couple types of sessions, but you can look at [DirectSession](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.h) for example. It ends up taking a `GraphDef` protocol buffer, which is executed when `Run` is called with feeds and fetches.